# Этимология слова "искупление"

Tags: этимология, лексика

Пожалуйста, мне срочно нужно найти происхождение слова "искупление". Заранее вам благодарна.

Answer (score 2):

ИСКУПИТЬ

Слово заимствовано из ст.-сл. языка, где было образовано префиксальным образом от "купити" (купить). Первоначальное значение - выкупить, впоследствии оно было переосмыслено: искупить вину.(Из этимологического словаря Г. Крылова).

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю позицию **[[@greydog](/users/3993/greydog)](/users/3993/greydog)**а. "Полный церковно-славянский словарь" Г.Дьяченко, страница 227,  [link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0227.htm) трактует ИСКУПЛЕНИЕ как перевод с греческого l’utron, в значении ВЫКУП, ИЗБАВЛЕНИЕ ОТ РАБСТВА. При этом ПЦСС акцентирует, что под ИСКУПЛЕНИЕМ особо "разумеется совершенное И.Христом дело нашего спасения, избавления его страданиями и смертью рода человеческого от греха, проклятия и смерти"." Однако, обратим внимание, в этом же словаре на следующее за ИСКУПЛЕНИЕМ слово ИСКУП, которое трактуется и как ВЫКУП, и как ВОЗМЕЗДИЕ. В последнем значении ИСКУПЛЕНИЕ=ИСКУП мы встречаем его в революционной песне "Смело, товарищи , в ногу..." . В ней есть слова: "Долго в цепях нас держали, /Долго нас голод томил, /Черные дни миновали, /Час **искупленья** пробил!". Безусловно, слово ИСКУПЛЕНИЕ здесь употреблено не в смысле выкупа *мировому капиталу* (что несовместимо с революционной теорией и практикой), а в смысле **возмездия**, **мщения**, **уничтожительной расплаты**.

Answer (score 0):

**Искупление** скорее происходит от «купель», нежели от «купити», поскольку и «искупление», и «купель» - слова, относящиеся к церковной лексике и близки по сути. **Купель** – сосуд для крещения, а так же водоём с холодной водой, нередко чудотворный, святой. Окунаясь в подобный холодный источник, человек испытывает некоторые телесные страдания, но очищается духовно – искупает грехи. Грехи нельзя выкупить, их можно смыть. Само же слово **купель** происходит от «купаться». Древний дохристианский праздник «Купалле» - «Купала», при котором люди совершали обряд очищения водой  и огнём, так же говорит о родственной связи **искупления** с **купелью** и **купанием**.

Comment: Всё-таки искупают грех и вину, а не себя (прямое дополнение, переход действия на объект).  Например: "Он хотел и не мог искупить какой-то свой тайный грех". "Я виноват, но я готов искупить вину"! Искупить - это не очистить себя, а совершить какое-либо благое дело, которое возместит дурной поступок. Словообразование: искупить - искупление, маловероятно: купель - искупить.

Comment: ..Проверил.. Был не прав. "Искупление" (в церковном значении) - "калька" с греческого "l’utron" - "выкуп". Права, всё-таки, @София.

Answer (score 0):

В основе искупления находится купа. На примере растительности: купы деревьев   это тесное соединение ветвей и листьев. Тоже самое в сообществе людей. За провинность могли выгнать из сообщества - искупить. В песне "час искупленья пробил" означает изгнание из страны представителей эксплуататорского класса.

Comment: Изгой мог вернуть расположение сообщества посредством совершения обряда очищения, благовидных дел, внесением денежных сумм.

Comment: Вообще-то слово ИСКУПЛЕНИЕ употребляется как возвышенно-религиозное понятие , и в революционную песню оно попало типа , как метафора . В церковном же языке употребляется не КУПА , а КУПИНА ("неопалимая купина" - горящий куст , возле которого Моисей беседовал с Богом ) , и было бы тогда не ИС-КУПЛ-ЕНИЕ , а ИС-КУПИН-ение . Ну , ладно , пусть будет КУПА . Но ваша смысловая связь КУПА(куст)-ИСКУПЛЕНИЕ(избавление от греха , вины) крайне расплывчата , если не сказать , что вовсе отсутствует . Усложнить ответ словесными пережёвываниями - это ещё не значит ответить правильно .

Comment: @Юриспрудент. Мой Вам совет: поменьше слушайте мудака Задорнова и ему подобных. Аминь.

Comment: @Юриспрудент. Вы напрасно ругаете ортодоксов. Какими бы они ни были "ортодоксальными", они хорошо подкованы и в славянских языках, и в греческом, и в иврите, и даже в санскрите. Корень КУП- им хорошо известен. Зайдите по ссылке в моем ответе на стр. 275-276. КУПА там дано в значениях КУЧА и ГРУППА, а не КУСТЫ, ВЕТКИ. КУСТ там КУПИНА. Там же с полдюжины других слов на КУП- со смыслом типа "совместно". Но слово ИСКУПЛЕНИЕ этот ПЦСС,тем не менее, с ним не связывает. Тут же простой смысл: надо что-то отдать, пожертвовать, чтобы от чего-то освободиться, избавиться. Т.е. дать ВЫКУП.